# Supremum of an almost surely continuous random process

Tags: continuity, elementary-proofs

I was learning this proposition

[image: this]

and now I have a question, how to prove it for an almost surely continuous process? I would be very grateful for any tips.

Comment: This has to do with the concept of *separability*  discussed  e.g. in Chapter 2 of Doob's  classic **Stochastic Processes**. If the paths of the process are almost surely continuous then the process  is separable in the sense of Doob  and then the $\sup$ and $\inf$ are measurable. This follows  mmediately from the definition of separability.